# Remove spacing between 2 words

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, trim

I am having one column containing both the first-name and second-name. Now i want to make a function which remove all the spaces between first name and last name and make 1st letter as as capital follow with the small letter.

For example if user type..

```
muKesH          AmBanI
```

then i will get the Output as a

```
Mukesh Ambani
```

only one space is der with 1st letter Capital by using MS SQL server.

Comment: Why do you store two informations in one column at all? Solve the real problem instead of fighting against the symptoms.

Comment: @TimSchmelter no i m storing in two column only but many users type there 1st name as well as middle name in the same Textbox and by mistake dey place mny spaces also so i wanna remove them.

Comment: _"then i will get the Output as a"_ actually means that this is what you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to build a function. After some inspiration from the manipulations available online, I adapted it to your query;

```
CREATE FUNCTION  FormatString(@text varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS 
declare @counter int, 
        @length int,
        @char char(1),
        @textnew varchar(4000)

    ' @text = 'muKesH          AmBanI'
    set @text       = rtrim(@text)
    set @text       = lower(@text)
    set @length     = len(@text)
    set @counter    = 1

    set @text = upper(left(@text, 1) ) + right(@text, @length - 1) 

    while @counter <> @length --+ 1
    begin
        select @char = substring(@text, @counter, 1)

        IF @char = space(1)  or @char =  '_' or @char = ','  or @char = '.' or @char = '\'
 or @char = '/' or @char = '(' or @char = ')'
        begin
            set @textnew = left(@text, @counter)  + upper(substring(@text, 
@counter+1, 1)) + right(@text, (@length - @counter) - 1)
            set @text    = @textnew
        end

        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end

    return replace(replace(replace(@text,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')

END
```

Comment: thank you so much i got it now this is the Pure answer which i want to get. a perfect work for my project. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
declare @var nvarchar(500)='muKesH    AmBanI'

select 
    STUFF(FN, 1, 1, UPPER(LEFT(FN, 1)))+' '+
    STUFF(LN, 1, 1, UPPER(LEFT(LN, 1)))
FROM(
    select 
        LOWER(SUBSTRING(@var, 1, charindex(' ', @var)-1)) FN,
        LOWER(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@var, charindex(' ', @var), 500))) LN
)x
```

AS function

```
CREATE FUNCTION  FormatString(@text varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS 
BEGIN

    SET @text=@text+' '

    SELECT @text=
        STUFF(FN, 1, 1, UPPER(LEFT(FN, 1)))+' '+
        ISNULL(STUFF(LN, 1, 1, UPPER(LEFT(LN, 1))), '')
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            LOWER(SUBSTRING(@text, 1, charindex(' ', @text)-1)) FN,
            LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@text, charindex(' ', @text), 500)))) LN
    )x

RETURN @text
END
```

Answer (score 1):

modified query according to output

```
DECLARE @t varchar(50)
SELECT @t = 'mukesh          AmBanI'
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(@t,1))+ SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(@t)),'  ',' '),'  ',''),2,5)+' '+
LEFT(LTRIM(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@t),PATINDEX('% %',@t )))),1)+LOWER(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@t),PATINDEX('% %',@t )))),2,5))
```

Comment: This doesn't init cap.

Comment: @PatrickHofman you want make the result as the same out put above shown.making capital letters also...

Comment: That's the request from OP, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100) = 'muKesH          AmBanI'
DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(100)
SET @Output = LOWER(STUFF(@Name, CHARINDEX(' ',@Name), LEN(@Name)-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@Name))+1-CHARINDEX(' ',@Name)+1,' '))
SET @Output = STUFF(@Output, CHARINDEX(' ',@Output)+1, 1, UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Output,CHARINDEX(' ',@Output)+1,1)))
SET @Output = UPPER(LEFT(@Output, 1)) + RIGHT(@Output, LEN(@Output)-1)

SELECT @Output
```